# Unable to setup connection to Azure SQL from DbFit

Tags: jdbc, azure-sql-database, dbfit

I am attempting to connect to SQL Azure using  the following JDBC connection string:

```
       !|Connect|jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.net,1433;databaseName=DBName;User=xxx@xxx;Password=xxxx;encrypt=true;LoginTimeout=30|
```

However each attempt will result in a Null error  being returned.

I am able to to connect to the SQL Azure from SSMS.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Port numbers require to be preceded by colons (:) and not commas (,). Try this: 
  !|Connect|jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxxx.xxxx.net:1433;databaseName=DBName;User=xxx@xxx;Password=xxxx;encrypt=true;LoginTimeout=30|


Check the connection string properties here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you building your connection string? You can use the ones provided at the Azure Portal, which will look like the following:

```
static String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{your_server}.database.windows.net:1433;database=test;user={username}@{your_server};password={your_password};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30";
```

Did you include the pipes in the string? You can follow this tutorial to ensure you're following the right steps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg715284.aspx